# http.ClientRequest error

Tags: node.js

When a request is thrown to my application, I send a request to another webserver. But at times, I receive some weird parse error I've never seen before.

Here is how the parse error looks like:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Parse Error
    at Socket.ondata (http.js:1150:24)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:354:27)
```

This is the code that I use to send the request:

```
var request = http.request(options);
request.end();
request.on('response', function (response) {
    response.on('end', function () {
        console.log('Response received');
    }
}
```

The question that I have is how can I mitigate this so I can throw the request again when this error occurs?

Comment: Have you verified that the server you are connecting to is returning proper HTTP data? Maybe try connecting with `telnet` or `nc` and confirm?

Comment: Yeah. My browser doesn't seem to be having an issue with it either.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you should be putting all your `.on()` listeners before you `.end()` in general since not all APIs `nextTick` their `.end()` method.

second of all, node's event emitters throw errors if you do not have a `.on('error')` listener. so your code should look more like this

```
var request = http.request(options)
request.on('response', function (response) {
  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log('Response received.')
  })
  response.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('I got a response error.')
    console.error(err.stack)
  })
})
request.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('I got a request error.')
  console.error(err.stack)
})
request.end()
```

Comment: I already found out about the 'error' listener after I posted this question, but I am still not sure of why this happens. Is there a way to access http.js and try to investigate the problem?

Comment: why what happens? what error happens, or why the error is thrown when there's no listener?

Comment: i would investigate `options`, not `http`

Comment: `Error: Parse Error` occurs. Same error that was shown in the question post. I think `options` are irrelevant.